# Chr() arg not in range python

Tags: python

I have been creating a program, and part of it involves modifying a list of characters at random:

```
    while rel>0:
        pos = random.randint(0,len(out)-1)
        change = random.randint(-1*rel,rel)
        if (change+ord(out[pos]))>=255:
            change = 255-ord(out[pos])
        elif ((ord(out[pos]))-change)<=0:
            change = -1*(ord(out[pos]))
        out[pos] = chr(ord(out[pos])+change)
        rel -= abs(change)
```

Here, rel is the 'currency' the program is using to modify the list of characters out. It first chooses a random position in the list, and a random amount of change for that position between -rel and +rel, then changes the value of that character using chr(ord(out[pos])+change). This was giving me the error that this new modified value for the character was out of the range(256), so I added the 2 if statements to be executed before changing the character, however it still occasionally returns this error, especially for large values of rel. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your choice of translation checks.

```
elif ((ord(out[pos]))-change)<=0:
```

Why is this difference meaningful?  All of the other operations are on the *sum* of the char and change.  You get the error when **change < -ord(out[pos])**: neither the **if** nor the **elif** condition is True, so you wind up taking the **chr** of a negative number.

Change that minus to a plus, and you should be fine, until you get values of rel beyond 512.  If this is possible, please consider using modulus (%) instead of a simple subtraction.

It took me a couple of minutes to trace this.  I cleaned up the program and added a pair of tracing **print**s to find out what's going on.

```
import random
out = list("Now is the time for all good parties")
rel = 500

while rel > 0:
    pos = random.randint(0, len(out)-1)
    chord = ord(out[pos])
    change = random.randint(-rel, rel)
    print "A", chord, change
    if change + chord >= 255:
        change = 255 - chord
    elif chord + change <= 0:
        change = -chord
    print "B", chord, change
    out[pos] = chr(chord + change)
    rel -= abs(change)

print ''.join(out)
```

Comment: Ah thank you!!! I was thinking subtracting, but of course change can be negative! Silly me.